# github - commit not having my changes not merged

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit, git-revert

I have committed my changes and pushed them to the remote git repository. But when I have pulled others changes to my master branch, It merged my repo and I didn't have my old chnages. There is something wrong with the pull request I have merged. Now I want to go to my stable commit which was made by me. Accordign to this git log, I want to go back to the "Final Integration" commit.

Here is the git log :

commit dc1276f241db392eb7785a655d6493c7cbdf712e
Merge: 0dd1453 e3281ec
Author: mehulkaklotar 
Date:   Fri Nov 1 04:01:27 2013 +0530

```
Vivek - Ranu Changes
```

commit 0dd14530bbbde1b4c7f00f4add96c2957ac9e373
Author: mehulkaklotar 
Date:   Fri Nov 1 03:53:40 2013 +0530

```
vendor menu - client place order (partial)- mehul
```

commit 5a3d6e8f3b2f257c46d43352f190c14dcd98b5fc
Author: mehulkaklotar 
Date:   Fri Nov 1 02:42:01 2013 +0530

```
Final Integration
```

commit e3281ece42ef5d049dc3f0958c7e611956183b84
Author: vshukla8991 
Date:   Thu Oct 31 08:23:42 2013 +0530

```
Commit: Changes by Vivek and Ranu
```

commit df8d19a478b11c6631e1b4dd8b5acef00dff7499
Author: vshukla8991 
Date:   Wed Oct 30 15:53:43 2013 +0530

```
Commit: Changes by Vivek
```

Comment: Please relax, sit back and take a deep breath. Then clearly and precisely type down what you did and what happened. Only then we can be able to help you. Try editing your question to explain in detail, the problem that you face.

Comment: i want to go back before the commit : Commit: Changes by Vivek and Ranu

Comment: You want to go to 'Final Integration' commit. is it?

Comment: no .. this commit  ... Commit: Changes by Vivek

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git reflog` you will see something like this

```
[some hash] HEAD@{[head pointer number]}: commit: Changes by Vivek
```

note down the [head pointer number], then do

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{[head pointer number]}
```

Comment: i am getting this error  ...  fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.

Comment: After resolving the conficts you have to add and commit them.

Comment: i am done with git reset --soft HEAD@{[head pointer number]} as u have told me to do. Now I should get my origianl changes?

Comment: First, please edit your question and post what exactly you see in your screen. do a git reflog and post it so that we can know.